# Does adding an ON clause to a JOIN statement make the query run faster?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a big query that is timing out.  Can I speed things up by adding specifying more join conditions for a table? Like going from this:

```
Left outer join table a on a.variable = b.variable
```

To this:

```
Left outer join table a on a.variable = b.variable and a.type = 'x'
```

Comment: It depends on your data and indexing; the main issue is those are two different queries, so it is not making the query run faster, but running a different (possibly faster) query.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you re actually using.

Comment: Also, if it is a big query, there is no way for us to really even guess how changing the JOIN will affect the performance. Why not post the actual query?

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

Your two queries do different things.  In general, it is a good idea to write the query to do what you want.

Under many circumstances, the second query will run faster because it would normally return a smaller result set.  This is not necessarily true, but it is a general guideline.